# Swift 2.3, how to report error to Instabug?

Tags: ios, swift, instabug

Integrated `Instabug` with my `swift 2.3` application, but seen the error reporting api of `Instabug` accepting `NSException` as following,

> Instabug.reportException(e)

But in swift 2.3, I am getting NSError instance within catch block.

```
do {

}
catch let error as NSError {

}
```

I want to report the error I am getting in my catch block to `Instabug`. Please let me know how I can do this.

Answer (score 1):

The `reportException` method is meant to be used with `NSException` objects, not `NSError`.

I believe you might be confusing how try/catch blocks work in Swift versus in other languages like Obj-C. try/catch in Swift should be used to handle recoverable errors, while it's used in Obj-C to handle unrecoverable errors.